# Extrapolating 2D image pixels using second order derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, signal-processing, image-processing

I intend to use image pixel data prediction to improve image compression. This means that I need predict image pixels based on previous rows and columns. I cannot use the next rows and columns for the computation.

Let's say I have information of the pixel above and left and left-above

```
data[i - 1, j - 1] , data[i - 1, j]
data[i, j - 1]     , ?
```

Then, how to approximate the current pixel `data[i, j]` ?

One way to achieve this is to accumulate the average of the values and average of the horizontal and vertical derivatives:

```
A = data[i - 1, j - 1]
B = data[i - 1, j]
C = data[i, j - 1]
D = data[i, j]

[A|B]
[C|D=?]
```

$$D \approx \frac{B+C}2 + \frac{(B-A) + (C-A)}2 = B + C - A$$

Therefore,

```
predicted_data[i, j] = data[i - 1, j] + data[i, j - 1] - data[i - 1, j - 1]
```

And this conforms with `Paeth` method used in `PNG` images before compression.

So far not problem.

The problem arises from when I have a larger matrices of $3\times3$ with the last element as an unknown value to be predicted.

```
data[i - 2, j - 2] , data[i - 2, j - 1] , data[i - 2, j]
data[i - 1, j - 2] , data[i - 1, j - 1] , data[i - 1, j]
data[i, j - 2]     , data[i, j - 1]     , data[i, j] = ?
```

Now, how can I extend this formulation to the second order curves for data prediction of `data[i, j]` ?

Is this extrapolation have any name that I can search in google and is there any research done on this topic?